# Select 2 with ajax remote data source doesn't select the correct options

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have setup a select 2 field vers 4.0.3, with a remote data source.

When I select the ith element in the list for the first time it selects the correct element. Afterwards if the list has changed and shows a different ith element and you click or press return to select the ith element, it still selects the element which was chosen the first time. So it seems that some attribute of the select2 field is not updated correctly.

I read that documentation and think that it might be connected to this warning:

For remote data sources only, Select2 does not create a new  element until the item has been selected for the first time. This is done for performance reasons. Once an  has been created, it will remain in the DOM even if the selection is later changed.

```
var remoteDataConfig = {
    placeholder: gene_glb,
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    allowClear: true,
    ajax: {
        url: '/genes_select',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function(term) {
            return {
                "org_db": "value",
                "searchterm": term
            };
        }
    }
};
$("#gene_select").select2(remoteDataConfig);
```

Edit: One possible "not quite solution" is to remove the selected element after each select.

```
$('#gene_select :selected').remove();
```

I'm still interested in how one could fix the configuration since this should happen automatically.